# Performing assignment operations on an object

Tags: javascript

Example JSFiddle so you can get a better idea of what is going on http://jsfiddle.net/brsXL/3/ (open your console and view the logged `vars` object).

I am building a parser and computer for a specific subset of maths in JavaScript, it takes an expression as a string from the user and allows them to use variables. To keep my computational logic simple but allow for the use of variables I have created an object that acts like a number but has the bonus of being passed by reference.

```
var Variable = function(value) {
    this.value = value || null;
}
Variable.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.value;
}
```

This works so that:

```
var a = new Variable(10);
console.log(a + 2); // = 12
console.log(a / 2); // = 5
```

However as soon as I wish to perform any form of assignment operation such as `+=` the object is lost and gets replaced by the result of the operation against the object's value property. e.g.

```
var a = new Variable(10);
console.log(a += 2); // = 12
console.log(a); // = 12
```

The reason I need it to work like this is because I want to use the same function to handle both numbers and variables. I could add code to each assignment operation but this feels sub-optimal to me, e.g.

```
var ops = {
   "+=" : function(a, b) {
      if (a instanceof Variable) {
         a.value += b;
      } else {
         a += b;
      }
      return a;
   },
   ...
}
```

But I'd much rather write:

```
var ops = {
   "+=" : function(a, b) {
      return a += b;
   },
   ...
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: what about refactoring to accommodate getters/setters? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Comment: @zamnuts's on the right track: user defined functions cannot return references.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy The `ops` functions aren't user defined, I have code which parses the users input and runs it through these predefined functions. The user would write `var a = 10; a += 12;`. This is just what goes on behind the scenes. They successfully return a reference, it's just the assignment operator overwrites the referenced copy of the object.

Comment: @zamnuts How would one define a setter for the entire Object? A setter refers to a property of an object no? If thats the case then I still have to check for the presence of an object in my `ops` functions and perform alternative logic.

Comment: @GeorgeReith super ugly, but perhaps extend Number to include a `value` property by adding a getter/setter for `Number.value`, so you have `return a.value += b.value` for all cases? Shot in the dark...

Comment: Unfortunately [compound assignment operators](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2) are specified to return the result and assign it to the initial identifier. The result is always a primitive (or error), so that's what you get back.

Comment: @GeorgeReith: sorry for the confusion.  If the code is in JavaScript and it's defined by **you** (not a built-in function of the browser), it cannot return references, whatever you do.  Operators cannot be defined, nor can they be modified.

Comment: @GeorgeReith two more thoughts: (1) if you're defining compound assignements, why does the functionality vs implementation have to be 1:1? for `ops["+="]` simply perform the operation/assignment then return; and in conjunction perhaps (2) force cast your primitives to `Variable`, e.g. `function(a,b){ a = new Variable(a); a.value += b.value; return a;}`

Comment: @zamnuts It doesn't have to it's just better this way, I want to allow users to write their own parsing functions and want to expose as little of the compilation logic to them as possible and allow them to focus on the numbers. Force casting within the functions wouldn't work as the compute function isn't aware of which variables it needs to store from the function it just stores and passes them along blindly at the moment allowing referencing to do it's thing, perhaps I need to redesign it to perform the assignment itself.

Comment: @zamnuts Basically this is vanity for my API. Thanks for the suggestions though they are very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd much rather write:
>
> ```
> function(a, b) {
>     return a += b;
> }
> ```
>
> Can this be done?

No. It's impossible to pass a Reference value as a single variable. You always will need to use object properties. `a` is always local-scoped in your function, so changing it won't affect the outer world. And I'd discourage you from trying to make your operators functions that operate on higher-scope variables…

I think in your case it's quite fine to use an explicit test for variables, because the assignment operator *has* to do that actually. You cannot assign to literals or other values, only to variables. It might even be

```
var ops = {
   "=" : function(a, b) {
      if (a instanceof Variable) {
         a.value = +b; // cast b to a number (from whatever it is)
         return a;
      } else {
         throw new Error("Invalid assignment to non-variable "+a);
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Also, to avoid code duplication you might not write out all the compound assignment operators. Define them in a generic way:

```
["+", "-", "*", "/"].forEach(function(op) {
    ops[op+"="] = function(a, b) {
        return ops["="].call(this, a, ops[op].call(this, a, b));
    };
});
```

([Updated jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brsXL/6/))